# RemoveAttr & add attr with ajax response first time works ,after

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When clicked a span with class `.editaRunses` ,trigger an ajax call to php file,php file return json whit data received the code tries put value inside each input,everything works except checkboxes,the firt time get the correct values (I tested every row and saw the data is correct) so the problem could be in removeAttr,the code run well once and before that not.

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.editaRunses' ,function(){
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "acciones.php?accion=recuperaRunses",
                data: {recuperaFormulario : id},
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                     $('#modificaRunses form').find('input').eq(0).val(response.Rope);
                     $('#modificaRunses form').find('input').eq(1).val(response.URL);
                     $('#modificaRunses form').find('textarea').eq(0).val(response.Proceso);
                     $('#modificaRunses form').find('textarea').eq(1).val(response.Observaciones);
                     $('#modificaRunses form').find('input').eq(2).val(response.Hora);
                     var cont  = 3;
                     $.each(response.Dias,function(ind,elem){
                            var sele = $('#modificaRunses form').find('input').eq(cont);
                            if (elem === "si"){ 
                                $(sele).attr('checked', 'checked');
                            }
                            else{
                                $(sele).removeAttr('checked', 'checked');
                            }
                            cont++;
                     });
                }
            });
        });
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modificaRunses" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Crea Departamento</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form role="form" action="" method="post">
                            <h3 class="text-center">Añade registro a la Runshet</h3>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Rope</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rope"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>URL Rope</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="url"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Proceso</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="proceso"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Observaciones</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="observaciones"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Hora (pon la hora con el formato 13:13)</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="hora"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Runshet donde ira (puedes seleccionar más de una)</label>
                                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Lunes" name="edicion[]" >Lunes - Jueves
                                </label>
                                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Viernes" name="edicion[]">Viernes
                                </label>
                                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Sabado" name="edicion[]">Sábado 
                                </label>
                                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Domingo" name="edicion[]">Domingo
                                </label>
                                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Local" name="edicion[]">Festivo Local
                                </label>
                                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Nacional" name="edicion[]">Festivo Nacional
                                </label>
                                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Especial" name="edicion[]">Festivo Especial
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group text-center">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success accion" data-accion="modificaRunses">Crear</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Volver</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The php works fine and return the correct values,but I show you

```
if($_GET["accion"] == "recuperaRunses"){
    $dias   = Array('Lunes','Viernes','Sabado','Domingo','Local','Nacional','Especial');
    $datos_json = $otro = array();
    $id  = $_POST['recuperaFormulario'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM runses WHERE Id = $id";
    $consulta = $db->consulta($sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
       $datos_json  = array('Rope' => $row['Rope'],'URL' => $row['URL'],'Proceso' => $row['Proceso'], 'Observaciones' => $row['Observaciones'] ,'Hora' => $row['Hora'],'Id' => $row['Id'] );
            $otro[$dias[$i]] = $row[$dias[$i]];
       }
    }
    $datos_json['Dias'] = $otro;
    echo json_encode($datos_json);
}
```

Comment: Use `.prop` instead of `.attr`

Comment: Change the line `$(sele).removeAttr('checked', 'checked');` instead of `$(sele).removeAttr('checked');`

Answer (score 2):

As documented in [how do i check uncheck a checkbox input or radio button/](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-check-uncheck-a-checkbox-input-or-radio-button/) you need to use [jQuery prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

I created a short snippet from your code so that if you try to use the button set/unset using attr/removeAttr you will experience the trouble.

While if you use the prop you will never get failure.

The snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#setChecked').on('click', function(e) {
    $(':checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
  })

  $('#unSetChecked').on('click', function(e) {
    $(':checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
  })

  $('#newSetChecked').on('click', function(e) {
    $(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
  })

  $('#newUnSetChecked').on('click', function(e) {
    $(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<button id="setChecked">Set Checked</button>
<button id="unSetChecked">UnSet Checked</button>
<button id="newSetChecked">USE PROP INSTEAD Set Checked</button>
<button id="newUnSetChecked">USE PROP INSTEAD  UnSet Checked</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="modificaRunses" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form role="form" action="" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Runshet donde ira (puedes seleccionar más de una)</label>
                        <label class="checkbox-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Lunes" name="edicion[]" >Lunes - Jueves
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Viernes" name="edicion[]">Viernes
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Sabado" name="edicion[]">Sábado
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Domingo" name="edicion[]">Domingo
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Local" name="edicion[]">Festivo Local
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Nacional" name="edicion[]">Festivo Nacional
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Especial" name="edicion[]">Festivo Especial
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```